# Take Ownership from retain or reference

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

I am writing a Rust parser toy, and I want to transform some nodes, there are three possible for this transform remove, keep, `ToTopLevel`, remove and keep is ok, but when I encounter `ToTopLevel`, I need to clone a node to push it into a temporary `Vec`, since it will delete node I wonder if there is any way I can get ownership and just give it to the temporary `Vec`.

```rs
use std::borrow::Cow;
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone)]
struct ASTNode<'a> {
    value: Cow<'a, str>,
    nodes: Vec<ASTNode<'a>>
}
struct Visitor<'a> {
    new_node: Vec<ASTNode<'a>>
}

enum Action {
    Remove,
    Keep,
    ToTopLevel,
}

impl<'a> Visitor<'a> {
    fn some_compute_to_determinate_action(&mut self, root: &mut ASTNode<'a>) -> Action {
        return Action::ToTopLevel;
    }
    fn visit(&mut self, root :&mut ASTNode<'a>) -> Action {
        let mut children_actions: Vec<Action> = Vec::new();
        for node in &mut root.nodes {
            children_actions.push(self.visit(node));
        }
        let mut index: usize = 0;
        root.nodes.retain(|node| {
            index+=1;
            match children_actions[index-1] {
                Action::Remove => false,
                Action::Keep => true,
                Action::ToTopLevel => {
                    // since it would delete node, is there are any way
                    // i can take ownership and push it to new_node vec ?
                    // like : self.new_node.push(*node);
                    self.new_node.push(node.clone());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return self.some_compute_to_determinate_action(root);
    }
    fn push_node_to_top_level_after_visit(&mut self,root: &mut ASTNode<'a>) {
        root.nodes.append(&mut self.new_node);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut root = ASTNode {
        value: Cow::Borrowed("root_value"),
        nodes: Vec::new()/*  assume there are a a lot of nested children  */
    };
    let mut visitor = Visitor {
        new_node: Vec::new()
    };
    visitor.visit(&mut root);
    visitor.push_node_to_top_level_after_visit(&mut root);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no iterator or method which hands off the item itself (it'd need something like `T -> Option<T>` as a callback, not sure why there isn't such a variant for `drain` and `retain` though, seems useful).

However since it's possible to create an `ASTNode` cheaply:

```
ASTNode {
    value: Cow::Borrowed(""),
    nodes: Vec::new()
}
```

what you can do is use [`Vec::retain_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain_mut) and [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to take the "actual" ASTNode out replacing it with a dummy which you then don't keep:

```
    root.nodes.retain_mut(|node| {
        index+=1;
        match children_actions[index-1] {
            Action::Remove => false,
            Action::Keep => true,
            Action::ToTopLevel => {
                self.new_node.push(std::mem::replace(node, ASTNode {
                    value: Cow::Borrowed(""),
                    nodes: Vec::new(),
                }));
                false
            }
        }
    });
```

or if you `derive(Default)` on `ASTNode`, just [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html)

```
    root.nodes.retain_mut(|node| {
        index+=1;
        match children_actions[index-1] {
            Action::Remove => false,
            Action::Keep => true,
            Action::ToTopLevel => {
                self.new_node.push(std::mem::take(node));
                false
            }
        }
    });
```